# OOP concept - where do you put the "getUserMembershipStorageSize()"

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I'm learning OOP concept right now and I have this problem.. I have two classes one is the User Class (the user model), and the Photos class.. now, I need a method to get the currentPhotoStorageSize available for the user. because user has only 10 Mb limit size.

how do i design it? I can put the method on the user but sure it's not a good design. please advise.

Comment: If it's up to me, the storage available for photos wouldn't belong to user, it would belong to photo storage.

Comment: Hopefully my answer helped you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to keep a good abstraction and split of concerns.

I would even go further and have a `Membership class`.

So it would be “getMembershipStorageSize()”

That way fields and data that are related with a Membership would go there and they would not clash with your User And Photo classes.

It would also allow you to be able to have Different types of Memberships with different max file size, etc.

That way your membership fields and data are decoupled from your User class and making it easy to maintain/change.